# Embed a bot in a DNN site

Tags: javascript, html, botframework, dotnetnuke, direct-line-botframework

I have to embed a bot of Microsoft Bot Framework inside a page built by a .Net Nuke (DNN). I cannot do that with an IFRAME because I have to insert parameters for the chat from the DNN so I followed [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat%C3%B9) example and inserted the chat window with Javascript and DirectLine. The problem now is that when I try to send a message to my bot the page reloads completely as it was a submit request from some html form. This is my code inside the `.ascx` file:

```
<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
<script>
  BotChat.App({
    directLine: { secret: direct_line_secret },
    user: { id: 'userid' },
    bot: { id: 'botid' },
    resize: 'detect'
  }, document.getElementById("div_of_the_bot"));
</script>
```

I have no idea why this happens and no idea how to modify the ms js script eventually, so I'm trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to prevent the default behavior to avoid the form submission. For example:

```
<div id="div_of_the_bot"></div>
<script>
    $(document).on("keypress", "#div_of_the_bot input",
        function (e) {
            if (e.which === 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        });
</script>
```

BTW, check the [DNN Webchat module](https://github.com/intelequia/dnn.webchat) that allows to integrate Bot Framework based chatbots into DNN, including support for Skype and Facebook channels. The module was recently presented at the DNN Connect 2018 by myself and is open source. Thanks to Javier Gracia from Intelequia for building it.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem now is that when I try to send a message to my bot the page reloads completely as it was a submit request from some html form.

The **Send** button will be rendered like below, and for most browsers the default type of button is ***submit***. So if you click send button, it submits form-data and page reloads.

[image]

To solve it, you can try:

1) set `type="button"` for send button

```
$("button.wc-send").attr("type", "button");
```

2) put your “div_of_the_bot” outside the  element

3) modify the source of WebChat, and [build your own  WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#building-web-chat). In ***Shell.tsx*** file:

```
private onKeyPress(e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {

        //prevent the default behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        this.sendMessage();
    }
}

private onClickSend(evt) {

    //prevent the default behavior
    evt.preventDefault();

    this.sendMessage();
}
```